# Swagger renders endpoint incorrectly for File+Json multipart/form-data endpoint

Tags: api, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm using ASP.NET Core 5 and I created a reusable model for multipart/form-data POST endpoints which accepts a file and a JSON as string. In order to make model validation work on the JSON part, I made this model generic, and added a custom model binder which deserializes the JSON to the given type parameter. It works perfectly if I post from Postman or from client side. But Swagger generates an incorrect UI for these endpoints.

My controller action looks like this:

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(DocumentConfigDetailsModel), StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden)]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyActionAsync([Required, FromForm] MultipartFormDataModel<MyModel> clientModel)
```

My model:

```
public class MultipartFormDataModel<T>
{
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }

    [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(MultipartJsonDataBinder))]
    public T FormDataModel { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is if I want to POST data from swagger UI, it puts the FormDataModel part in the query, not in the request body as form data. The File part is ok, I can browse a file and POST it.

Is there a way to make swagger send the FormDataModel part as form-data in the body?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Some time ago I've made a small library to make it possible:

https://github.com/Morasiu/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.JsonMultipartFormDataSupport

You can use it or just use code from it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @morasiu! Sorry for the slow response, but I had not time to deal with this until now. I got the UI to be as expected with the use of parts of your code. My problem is that I cannot execute the request. Nothing happens when I click on the `Execute` button. Do you have any idea what am I missing?
I used the OperationFilter, the BinderProvider and the FromJsonAttribute. I have my own model and modelBinder, but they are basically the same as yours.

Comment: That could be a lot of things. Try launching Swagger UI in Incognito mode and check the browser console for errors.

Comment: Thanks, but the console is absolutely empty. Network tab is all good as well, except that my request is not sent.

Comment: You can try adding my lib and tell me if it's the same for you?

Comment: Sure. I added your lib, the only difference is that this way I can send an empty request at least. But when I add data to either to the json part or a file, the request is no longer sent :(

I checked my versions, maybe it helps: Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger 6.2.3, Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen 6.2.3, Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI 6.1.1

Comment: Oh... Hm... Can you report an Issue on Github? I will check it later probably